# "New Screenshot" button is disabled in XCode Organizer

Tags: iphone, mac, xcode, screen-capture

I have connected my iPhone to my Mac.. 
When I open XCode Organizer, the New Screenshot button is disabled.. 
Any idea why???

XCode Version 4.3.2
iOS 6.0.1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the iDevice
2. Click "Use for development"
3. Enter your Apple ID and password

Now you should be able to take screenshots.

Comment: Can you please accept if this is helpful.